# Why wasn't the `user-select` property standardised?

Tags: css, cross-browser, textselection

Questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/) and particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358620/1543908) answer point to the standards proposal page [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select), but it was never actually standardised.
What was the reasoning behind this? Why do we still have to exclusively use vendor prefixes or JavaScript for this?

Relevant [CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/) and [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none) pages.

Comment: Not sure, but FWIW, [it's back in UI level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#content-selection).